# No transaction active Error message in a distributed transaction while MSDTC is enabled

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a linked server from server1 to server2.
server1

```
operating system: windows server2003 sp2
SQL server: SQL server 2008 R2
```

server2:

```
operating system: windows server2003 R2
SQL server: SQL server 2k Sp3
```

`MSDTC` is enabled on both pcs, but when I have such a distributed transaction I encounter following error:

```
set xact_abort on
begin distributed transaction
select * from linkedserver1.DbWorkshops.dbo.tbl_Workers
commit
```

Error message:

```
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "Linkedserver1" returned message "No transaction is active.".
Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "Linkedserver1" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.
```

Comment: how is this question different to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858303/ole-db-provider-sqlncli-for-linked-server-xxx-returned-message-no-transacti  ???

Answer (score 1):

It could be permissions or a firewall issue.

See [Troubleshooting MSDTC issues with the DTCPing tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2008/11/12/troubleshooting-msdtc-issues-with-the-dtcping-tool.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In Linked server transactions, MSDTC tries to communicate with the dns addresses, not the ip address of the servers. Therefore, it is necessary to make the necessary configuration in the host file of the servers. It took me a lot of time and that's how we figured it out.