# Distributed Transactions on SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, transactions, msdtc

I am trying to execute a stored procedure on linked server B from inside a trigger on server A.

When I do this I get the error:

> No transaction is active.

and the transaction is aborded.

I have already followed the answers provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858356/no-transaction-active-error-message-in-a-distributed-transaction-while-msdtc-is), but to no avail. DTCPing works perfectly fine, so the RPC calls are working correctly.
On Server A, I have configured the component to use the local DTC and enbled all logging options.

The trace file only contains 9 messages, but the traceview.exe provided by the WDK cannot format them.

Can you provide me with any more hints, on where to look?
Also, when having the option 'Use local DTC' enabled on Server A, do I need to enable it on server B as well?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's usually a *really* bad idea to couple code running inside a trigger to *anything* outside of its own database. Do you really want transaction on server A to be pausing for long network latencies and an eventual failure if Server B is unavailable for any length of time? It's usually far better to queue such interactions (via a table or service broker, etc) and let the original transaction complete.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Since one of the requirements is realtime execution of the functionality, I will try to move the datastructure from server B back to server A.

Comment: Ok, problem solved. There authentiction modes where not properly set on both MSDTCs.

Comment: Can I close the question myself?